# Inline picture not displaying in receiver's Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The below code sends emails from an Excel file.

Inline pictures are not displaying on the receiving email if sent via code.

If I send manually it will display it but if more than 80 drafts email are created Outlook will crash.

```vb
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Dim sigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim insertPhoto As String
    Dim photoSize As String
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    sigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                        "\Microsoft\Signatures\Mysig.htm"
    If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If
    
    insertPhoto = "C:\Users\store\Desktop\Presale.jpg" 'Picture path
    photoSize = "<img src=""cid:Presale.jpg""height=400 width=400>" 'Change image name here
    
    emailMessage = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Dear " & titleName & " " & fullName & "," & _
                    "<p>I hope my email will find you very well." & _
                    "<p>Our <strong>sales preview</strong> starts on Thursday the 22nd until Sunday the 25th of November." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to welcoming you into the store to shop on preview.<p>" & _
                    "<p> It really is the perfect opportunity to get some fabulous pieces for the fast approaching festive season." & _
                    "<p>Please feel free to contact me and book an appointment." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to seeing you then." & _
                    "<p>" & photoSize & _
                    "<p>Kind Regards," & _
                    "<br>" & _
                    "<br><strong>My Name</strong>" & _
                    "<br>Assistant Store Manager" & _
                    "<p>"
    
    With outlookMail
        .To = clientEmail
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "PRIVATE SALE | IN STORE"
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .Attachments.Add insertPhoto, 1, 0
        .HTMLBody = emailMessage & Signature 'Including photo insert and signature
        .Importance = 2
        .ReadReceiptRequested = True
        .Display
        '.Send 'this will send the email without review / not showing picture inserted
    End With
    
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set outlookMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Could be the Size of the image?

Comment: @0m3r Everything is working perfectly and can be seen on any device properly if you only do .display and then manually press send. If it’s straight.send then you see an empty white box instead of the image. In addition you can only create about 80 email at any given time after that outlook crashes.

Comment: You are correct, you will need to display the email once inline is attached, then use `.send` before `End With`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for answers on this topic i have revised the below and tested it and working perfectly.

```
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Dim sigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim insertPhoto As String
    Dim photoSize As String
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    sigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Mysig.htm"
    If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    insertPhoto = "C:\Users\store\Desktop\Presale.jpg" 'Picture path
    photoSize = "<img src=""cid:Presale.jpg""height=400 width=400>" 'Change image name here

    emailMessage = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Dear " & titleName & " " & fullName & "," & _
                    "<p>I hope my email will find you very well." & _
                    "<p>Our <strong>sales preview</strong> starts on Thursday the 22nd until Sunday the 25th of November." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to welcoming you into the store to shop on preview.<p>" & _
                    "<p> It really is the perfect opportunity to get some fabulous pieces for the fast approaching festive season." & _
                    "<p>Please feel free to contact me and book an appointment." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to seeing you then." & _
                   "<p>" & photoSize & _
                    "<p>Kind Regards," & _
                    "<br>" & _
                    "<br><strong>My Name</strong>" & _
                    "<br>Assistant Store Manager" & _
                    "<p>"


    With outlookMail
        .To = clientEmail
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "PRIVATE SALE | IN STORE"
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .Attachments.Add insertPhoto, 1, 0
        .HTMLBody = emailMessage & Signature 'Including photo insert and signature
        .Importance = 2
        .ReadReceiptRequested = True
        .Display
        .Send

    End With

    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set outlookMail = Nothing
End Sub
```